# Why "resizeTo" doesn't works

Tags: javascript

My code works for "open" and "close" the new window, but why not for `resizeTo`?

```html
<button id='modifier'>Modifier la fenêtre</button>
```

```js
var modifier = document.getElementById('modifier');
var fenetre = '';

modifier.addEventListener('click', fModifier);

function fOuvrir(){
  fenetre = window.open('http://pierre-giraud.com','blank','width = 500, height = 600');
}

function fModifier(){
  fenetre.resizeTo(300, 300);
}
function fFermer(){
  fenetre.close();
}
```

Comment: this is the error message in chrome:

Comment: open_close_resize_fenetre.html:31 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:50996" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLButtonElement.fModifier (http://127.0.0.1:50996/open_close_resize_fenetre.html:31:25)
fModifier @ open_close_resize_fenetre.html:31

Comment: Are you on the same domain as http://pierre-giraud.com ?, if not then you can't control the window after you open it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you didn't call the fOuvrir().

```
            function fModifier(){
fOuvrir();
                fenetre.resizeTo(300, 300);
            }
```

Comment: Sorry but if I copy/ past all code, i can't submite the message.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `fmodifier()` without calling `fouvrir()` first.

You can't resize a window/tab that hasn't been created by `window.open`.

Consider adding `fOuvrir();` to your `fmodifier()` function.

Comment: did you opened the link for get the code in totality ?

Comment: The link is in your localhost, I cannot open it… as I said you can't resize a window that hasn't been created first by `window.open`